# Опечатка: двойной знак вопроса в подсказке о местоположении

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

При редактировании поля местоположения в профиле в подсказке фигурируют два знака вопроса подряд.

> Вы имели в виду `Город, Страна`??

[image: скриншот проблемы]

Проблема специфичная для ru.SO и на других ресурсах сети StackExchange не наблюдается, ошибка явно допущена в процессе локализации.

Comment: Всего пять месяцев прошло)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, был лишний «?». Строка: [Tx:4763](http://%20https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266709?key=232556b54509875ead21a939871781a0). Исправлено.